# Destructuring when have duplicate keywords

Tags: clojure

Destructuring maps, for example with `{:keys [x y]} m`, cannot be done in function paramters when there are going to be many maps (say `m0`, `m1`) of the same *type*. Here doing so would result in `x` and `y` being shadowed. So instead this is what I am doing for the point *type*:

```
(defn intersection [point0 
                    point1]
  (let [x0 (:x point0)
        y0 (:y point0)
        x1 (:x point1)
        y1 (:y point1)]))
```

What is a cleaner (more idiomatic) way of achieving the above? I want a point to always have the keys `:x` and `:y`, rather than resorting to the first point having keys `:x0` and `:y0`, and the second having `:x1` and `:y1`.

same *type* = "consistent names in the input maps"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I assume you are asking to have consistent names in the input maps, so every points has the keys :x and :y: then you can use the other syntax for map destructuring:

```
{name key-to-use ...}
```

the `:keys` form is a shortcut for this form.

If the points are passed as their own arguments:

```
user> (def p1 {:x 0  :y 1})
#'user/p1
user> (def p2 {:x -3  :y -8})
#'user/p2

user> (defn example [{x0 :x y0 :y} {x1 :x y1 :y}]
        [x0 x1 y0 y1])
#'user/example
user> (example p1 p2)
[0 -3 1 -8]
```

If you are passing a list of points then you can nest map and list destructuring

```
user> (defn example [[{x0 :x y0 :y} {x1 :x y1 :y}]]
        [x0 x1 y0 y1])
#'user/example
user> (example [p1 p2])
[0 -3 1 -8]
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this "alternate" syntax - it is the basic map destructuring syntax, on which stuff like `:keys` is built as a convenience layer.

Comment: Thats true, it's the alternative to that one he used. I'll change it to "other syntax"

Answer (score 2):

You can choose which names is bound to a key:

```
(let [{x1 :x y1 :y} m1 
      {x2 :x y2 :y} m2]
  (foo x1 y1 x2 y2))
```

See also the following example from [Destructuring in Clojure](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring):

```
(def my-map {:a "A" :b "B" :c 3 :d 4})
(let [{a :a, x :x, :or {x "Not found!"}, :as all} my-map]
  (println "I got" a "from" all)
  (println "Where is x?" x))
;= I got A from {:a "A" :b "B" :c 3 :d 4}
;= Where is x? Not found!
```